# Does ASP.NET Identity 2 assign roles to user automatically on Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, roles, asp.net-identity-2

I implement Group-Based Permissions Management in an MVC project as on [ASP.NET Identity 2.0: Implementing Group-Based Permissions Management](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/808903/asp-net-identity-implementing-group-based-permissi). As far as I know, there is no need to assign roles to user and after user logins, ASP.NET Identity will automatically assign all the roles in the RoleGroup that the user has. However, although I created the related Role and RoleGroup and then add the user to this group (in ApplicationUserGroups table), the user roles cannot be assigned in Login action. So, is there a manual assign is needed? Or what is the problem?

***AccountController:***

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, 
model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error: LockedOut");
            return View(model);
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error: RequiresVerification");
            return View(model);
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong username or password");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anybody else use ASP.NET Identity 2??? Any idea please?

Comment: Yes I do use it. Your user does have the connection to their roles automatically, however if you want to be able to access that information elsewhere in your application you need to store it somewhere, the user principle, in a cookie, etc. What exactly are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kyle Many thanks for your answer. Yes, ASP.NET Identity 2.0 automatically assign roles on Login. The point I missed is that: **When assigning a user to a group, ASP.NET Identity 2.0 also assign all the roles in this user group to the related user**. So, when creating roles on database manually, it must be keep into account and roles must also be added to the related user besides usergroup :) Many thanks...